# PHP filtering JSON arrays

Tags: php, json, parsing, fullcalendar, filtering

I'm new to php and I'm trying to filter JS FullCalendar JSON feed with extra parameter, but haven't found solution yet. I managed to make index file to send parameter to query but not able to filter coming data with it like checking event is date range on last lines of this php file.

```
   <?php

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // This script reads event data from a JSON file and outputs those events which are within the range
    // supplied by the "start" and "end" GET parameters.
    //
    // An optional "timezone" GET parameter will force all ISO8601 date stings to a given timezone.
    //
    // Requires PHP 5.2.0 or higher.
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Require our Event class and datetime utilities
    require dirname(__FILE__) . '/utils.php';

    // Short-circuit if the client did not give us a date range.
    if (!isset($_GET['start']) || !isset($_GET['end'])) {
        die("Please provide a date range.");
    }

    // Parse the start/end parameters.
    // These are assumed to be ISO8601 strings with no time nor timezone, like "2013-12-29".
    // Since no timezone will be present, they will parsed as UTC.
    $range_start = parseDateTime($_GET['start']);
    $range_end = parseDateTime($_GET['end']);
   // Get user info 
    $user = $_GET['user'];
    // Parse the timezone parameter if it is present.
    $timezone = null;
    if (isset($_GET['timezone'])) {
        $timezone = new DateTimeZone($_GET['timezone']);
    }

    // Read and parse our events JSON file into an array of event data arrays.
    $json = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../json/events.json');
    $input_arrays = json_decode($json, true);


    // Accumulate an output array of event data arrays.
    $output_arrays = array();
    foreach ($input_arrays as $array) {

        // Convert the input array into a useful Event object
        $event = new Event($array, $timezone);

        // If the event is in-bounds, add it to the output
        if ($event->isWithinDayRange($range_start, $range_end)){
            $output_arrays[] = $event->toArray();
        }
    }

    // Send JSON to the client.
    echo json_encode($output_arrays);
```

Example of feed:

```
{ "user": "Max", "company": "ex1",     "start": "2016-03-16T07:00:00",     "end": "2016-03-16T14:30:00",     "info": " "},
{ "user": "Max", "company": "ex2",      "start": "2016-03-17T07:00:00",     "end": "2016-03-17T14:30:00",     "info": " "},
{ "user": "Sam", "company": "e3",      "start": "2016-03-18T07:00:00",     "end": "2016-03-18T14:30:00",     "info": " "},
```

Purpose is get lines with user "Max" only. I have tried various PHP functions but it always gives error like:
  (Warning message "Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array).

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't see a "?" in this "question"

Comment: Show an example of your `.json` input file please. _Add it to your question, dont put it in a comment_

Comment: At least his code is thoroughly documented..

Comment: Use a simple `if` statement in your `foreach` loop that checks the value of the `user` key – and `continue`s if it does not equal Max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to CBroe I got it.

```
// Accumulate an output array of event data arrays.
$output_arrays = array();
foreach ($input_arrays as $array) {
  if($array['user'] == $user) {
    // Convert the input array into a useful Event object
    $event = new Event($array, $timezone);

    // If the event is in-bounds, add it to the output
    if ($event->isWithinDayRange($range_start, $range_end)){
        $output_arrays[] = $event->toArray();
    }}
}
```